# Is there a way to implement this integer casting function with unsafe Pointer in golang?

Tags: go, casting, unsafe

I was wondering if I could implement a less verbose version of this function. It would be great if it had better performance.

```golang
func AnyIntToInt(x interface{}) (int, error) {
    switch val := x.(type) {
    case int8:
        return int(val), nil
    case int16:
        return int(val), nil
    case int32:
        return int(val), nil
    case int64:
        return int(val), nil
    case uint8:
        return int(val), nil
    case uint16:
        return int(val), nil
    case uint32:
        return int(val), nil
    case uint64:
        return int(val), nil
    }
    return 0, ErrNotInteger
}
```

I have been trying with this one, however it yields unexpected results.

```
func AnyIntToInt(x interface{}) (int, error) {
    return *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(&x))
}
```

Comment: No, there is not shortcut using the unsafe package.   The code in the unsafe version of the function incorrectly assumes that all integer and unsigned types have the same memory layout as an `int`.

Comment: I think the unsafe version of your code yields unexpected results because it's attempting to reinterpret the interface itself, instead of the value boxed therein. However even if you got that right, Cerise Limon's comment still applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question is the way to go, but you can reduce lines of code using the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package:

```
func AnyIntToInt(x interface{}) (int, error) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        return int(v.Int()), nil
    case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
        return int(v.Uint()), nil
    }
    return 0, ErrNotInteger
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/gJ4ASo7AeyN